# Pattern required for adding/updating entities in EF5 including relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using VS 2010 with Entity Framework 5 code first and C# and have a web application (hence disconnected entities). I am used to working with SQL queries directly but am very new to EF and code first.

I have two classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID {get; set;}
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuspended { get; set; }
    public int UnitID { get; set; }
    public virtual MyTrust MyTrusts { get; set; }        
}

public class MyTrust
{
    public int MyTrustID { get; set; }
    public string MyTrustName { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public bool DoNotUse { get; set; }        
}
```

and my DbContext class contains:

```
public DbSet<MyTrust> MyTrust { get; set; }
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

 modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasRequired(m => m.MyTrust);
```

The MyTrust entity will not be changed
There are three scenarios I am interested in:

- Adding a user with an existing MyTrust
- Updating a user with no change to the trust
- Updating a user with a change to the trust

When the website returns the data the MyTrust object has only the MyTrustID set. When I update/add the user the MyTrust record is also updated.

**CLARIFICATION** The relationship in the User object is NOT updated; the actual MyTrust object is updated with the data returned from the website; as most fields are empty this is corrupting the object AND not achieving the required update of the User record.

In fact, the problem seems to boil down to the fact that the wrong end of the relationship is being updated.

I have looked at some many examples I cannot see a simple solution.

Can anyone please suggest a straightforward pattern for this (it was so easy in the SQL days).

**UPDATE**
I resolved this by adding specific keys to the User and MyTrust classes.

```
public int NHSTrustID { get; set; }
```

and a matching key in the MyTrust class.

In retrospect the question was wrong. I wasn't after patterns but the solution to a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given some examples below - I've done them from memory but hopefully will give you a good starting point:

Adding a user with an existing MyTrust

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext()){
    context.Entry(myUser).State = EntityState.Added

    context.Entry(myUser.MyTrusts).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.Entry(myUser.MyTrusts).Property(x => x.MyTrustName).IsModified = false;
    context.Entry(myUser.MyTrusts).Property(x => x.Region).IsModified = false;
    context.Entry(myUser.MyTrusts).Property(x => x.DoNotUse).IsModified = false;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Updating a user with no change to trusts:

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext()){
    context.Entry(myUser).State = EntityState.Modified
    context.Entry(myUser.MyTrusts).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Updating a user with a change to trusts:

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext()){
    context.Entry(myUser).State = EntityState.Modified
    context.Entry(myUser.MyTrusts).State = EntityState.Modified;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt and thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, this does not really solve the problem as I want to exclude the MyTrust object from the update. I just want to update the relationship in the User object. See clarification above.

Comment: Hi Peter - is the User to MyTrust relationship 'one to one' or 'one to many'?

Comment: Hi Matt - for ultimate clarification. Every user must have one trust; any trust can have may users.

Comment: Could you add public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } to your MyTrust class?